# In Android Studios, when clicked on product list item, display corresponding prices for that product

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been looking for an answer high and low to my problem. Here it goes... I have products to display in a list and some of these products could have more than one amount of units and prices. I have the model class defined, my DBAdapter that creates my tables and I am pullParsing data from XML sheets which all looks great.

The problem I have is how to retrieve and display data from multiple tables in the SQLite database. I thought I could retrieve that data separately into two different lists and combine the lists but I need to keep my product_id and price_id linked so I get the correct units and prices for that product. Any help would be appreciated and helpful.

My DBAdapter that creates my tables

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "FarrellDB";

    //DATABASE NAME AND VERSION
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "farrell.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    // Product Table Field Names
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String PRODUCT_ID = "product_id";
    public static final String PRODUCT_SKU = "sku";
    public static final String PRODUCT_DESC = "desc";

    // Price Table Field Names
    public static final String TABLE_PRICES = "prices";
    public static final String PRICE_ID = "id";
    public static final String PRICE_ID_ID = "price_id";
    public static final String PRICE_UNITS = "units";
    public static final String PRICE_PRICE = "amount";

    //SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCTS
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCTS =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " (" + PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PRODUCT_SKU + " TEXT, " + PRODUCT_DESC + " TEXT " +
        ")";

    //SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PRICES
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PRICES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRICES + " (" + PRICE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PRICE_ID_ID + " INTEGER, " + PRICE_UNITS + " INTEGER, " + PRICE_PRICE + " NUMERIC " +
        ")";


    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PRICES);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Tables have been created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRICES);
        onCreate(db);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database has been upgraded from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
    }
}

public class ProductViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "FarrellDB";

    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_view);

        dataSource = new DataSource(this);
        dataSource.open();

        List < Product > products = dataSource.findAllProducts();
        if (products.size() == 0) {
            insertProductData();
            insertPriceData();
            products = dataSource.findAllProducts();
        }

        ArrayAdapter < Product > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < Product > (this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
        ListView product_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.product_list_view);
        product_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);


        // WHEN THE USER CLICKS ON A ITEM IN THE LIST GOES TO THE NEW ACTIVITY
        product_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductViewActivity.this, PriceListViewActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_product_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        dataSource.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        dataSource.close();
    }

    public void insertProductData() {
        ProductPullParser parser = new ProductPullParser();
        List < Product > products = parser.parseXML(this);

        for (Product product: products) {
            dataSource.createProduct(product);
        }
    }

    public void insertPriceData() {
        PricePullParser parser = new PricePullParser();
        List < Price > prices = parser.parseXML(this);

        for (Price price: prices) {
            dataSource.createPrice(price);
        }
    }
}

public class DataSource {

    public static final String LOGTAG = "FarrellDB";

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBAdapter(context);
    }

    public void open() {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database Opened");
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database Closed");
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Product createProduct(Product product) {
        ContentValues productValues = new ContentValues();
        productValues.put(DBAdapter.PRODUCT_SKU, product.getSku());
        productValues.put(DBAdapter.PRODUCT_DESC, product.getDesc());
        long insertid = database.insert(DBAdapter.TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, productValues);
        product.setProduct_id(insertid);
        return product;
    }

    public Price createPrice(Price price) {
        ContentValues priceValues = new ContentValues();
        priceValues.put(DBAdapter.PRICE_ID_ID, price.getPrice_id());
        priceValues.put(DBAdapter.PRICE_UNITS, price.getUnits());
        priceValues.put(DBAdapter.PRICE_PRICE, price.getAmount());
        long insertid = database.insert(DBAdapter.TABLE_PRICES, null, priceValues);
        price.setId(insertid);
        return price;
    }

    public List < Product > findAllProducts() {
        List < Product > products = new ArrayList < Product > ();
        List < Price > prices = new ArrayList < Price > ();
        List final_list = new ArrayList();

        final_list.addAll(products);
        final_list.addAll(prices);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "final_list contains " + final_list);

        String productQuery = "SELECT products.sku, products.desc, prices.units, prices.amount " +
            "FROM products, prices " +
            "WHERE products.product_id = prices.price_id";

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(productQuery, null);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned products " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setProduct_id(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRODUCT_ID)));
                product.setSku(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRODUCT_SKU)));
                product.setDesc(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRODUCT_DESC)));
                products.add(product);
            }
        }
        return products;
    }

    public List < Price > findAllPrices() {
        List < Price > prices = new ArrayList < Price > ();

        String priceQuery = "SELECT products.sku, products.desc, prices.units, prices.amount " +
            "FROM products, prices " +
            "WHERE products.product_id = prices.price_id";

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(priceQuery, null);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned products " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Price price = new Price();
                price.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRICE_ID)));
                price.setPrice_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRICE_ID_ID)));
                price.setUnits(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRICE_UNITS)));
                price.setAmount(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.PRICE_PRICE)));
                prices.add(price);
            }
        }
        return prices;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass your two lists to the same adapter display them one after the other, or mix them into one list and then display the items.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can combine two different items into an incredibly basic list very easily such as name and number. Its when you go past that, you need a custom way of doing so.

For instance I use this class in my own code as a custom way of pulling quite a lot together into a list (but there's different ways of doing so) and this one works for me:

```
private class CustomListAdapterH extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    // Implement all required methods

    // private View createViewFromResource(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int resource) {
           // EXAMPLE:
           // priceTextView.setText(price[position]);
    // }
}
```

You can use images, OnClickListeners, and pretty much everything from that list. You'll also have to learn how to make the list smooth by not doing as much as possible inside the method that creates the items as the user scrolls or it'll scroll badly as it keeps repeating the code.

If you need more you can just google search it. Its there.

Your into the complicated stuff here so relax cause it'll take quite a bit of work.